# Get Wifi scan Result List in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

I want to receive all avaiable wifi to a ResultList using broadcastReceiver override method onReceive(). Don't know why I cannot go into my override method ( Can't catch breakpoint at println("On receive active") )

After that I checked resultList by "If" statement but it occures that resultList is empty.
What am I doing wrong ?

My code below :

```
class AddNewDeviceFragment : Fragment() {


var resultList = ArrayList<ScanResult>()

private var adapter: NewDeviceAdapter = NewDeviceAdapter(arrayListOf())
private lateinit var model: NewDeviceViewModel
private lateinit var rootView: View

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_addnewdevice, container, false)

    return rootView
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    var newDevicesRecycledView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.newDevicesRecycledView) as RecyclerView
    newDevicesRecycledView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    newDevicesRecycledView.adapter = adapter

    //ViewModel
    model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NewDeviceViewModel::class.java)

    //LiveData
    model.getNewDevices()
        .observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<MutableList<NewDevice>> { newDevices ->
            adapter.addDevice(newDevices)
        })

    refreshButton.setOnClickListener { startScan() }
}

fun startScan() {
    model.clearAllData()
    val wifiManager = context?.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager

    val broadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
            resultList = wifiManager.scanResults as ArrayList<ScanResult>
            println("On receive active")

            for (result in resultList) {
                model.addNewDevice(NewDevice(result.SSID.toString()))
            }
        }
    }

    if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Wifi is disable... We need to enable it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true)
    }

    context?.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION))

    if(resultList.isEmpty())
        Toast.makeText(activity,"ResultList empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


    wifiManager.startScan()
    Toast.makeText(activity,"Scanning Wifi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
}
```

Comment: My targetSdkVersion 28, compileSdkVersion 28 and minSdkVersion 26. In Manifest I include ACCES_FINE_LOCATION, ACCES_COARSE_LOCATION permissions

Comment: ACCES_WIFI_STATE too